# BNR book-Swift Ch 22, gold challenge-A solution in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3

This is a Swift 3.0 version of a previously presented Swift 2.0 solution.

```
import Cocoa


func findAll<T: Equatable, C: Collection>(items: C, itemToFind: T) -> [C.Index]?  where C.Iterator.Element == T  {

  guard items.contains(itemToFind) else {
    return nil
  }

  var result = Array<C.Index>()
  var index = items.startIndex
  for item in items {
    if item == itemToFind {
      result.append(index)
    }
    index = items.index(after: index)   //    index = index.successor()
  }
  return result      
}



print("\nList the Indicies within 'items' of where 'itemToFind' was found")


let Indexes = findAll([items: [5, 3, 7, 3, 9], itemToFind: 3)                    // result expected: [1, 3]
let Indexes = findAll([items: ["c", "a", "b", "c", "a"], itemToFind: "b")        // result expected: [1, 4]


let stringChars = ["Hello, playground!".characters]
let stringIndexes = findAll(items: stringChars, itemToFind: Character("l"))         // result expected: [2, 3, 8]
```

The compiler doesn't help me, the only errors reported complain about "expected ',' separator missing in the 4 statements after the only print statement.
Can anyone point out where I've either written the routine incorrectly or miss-understood how to input the parameters in the call to the 'findAll' function?

Answer (score 0):

```
let Indexes = findAll([items: [5, 3, 7, 3, 9], itemToFind: 3)
                      ^
```

This line has a stray square bracket at the location I've marked. Remove it.

```
let Indexes = findAll([items: ["c", "a", "b", "c", "a"], itemToFind: "b")
```

Same problem, same place. Also, I'm not sure why you expect this to return `[1, 4]` -- if you'd passed `itemToFind: "c"` I'd agree, but `"b"` only appears once, at position `[2]`.

(Also, you'll need to name the variable something other than `Indexes` -- that name is already in use from the previous line.)

```
let stringChars = ["Hello, playground!".characters]
```

Wouldn't you know it, this line doesn't need *either* of its square brackets! `characters` is already a CharacterView (which behaves enough like an array for `findAll()` to work); it doesn't need to be wrapped into another level of array.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Swift 3.0

```
import Cocoa


func findAll<T: Equatable, C: Collection>(items: C, itemToFind: T) -> [C.Index]?  where C.Iterator.Element == T  {

  guard items.contains(itemToFind) else {
    return nil
  }

  var result = Array<C.Index>()
  var index = items.startIndex
  for item in items {
    if item == itemToFind {
      result.append(index)
    }
    index = items.index(after: index)   //    index = index.successor()
  }
  return result

  //  Another approach:
  //  return items.indices.filter { items[$0] == itemToFind }

}

print("\nList the Indicies within 'items' of where 'itemToFind' was found")


let Indexes1 = findAll(items: [5, 3, 7, 3, 9], itemToFind: 3)                    // result: [1, 3]
print(Indexes1!)
let Indexes2 = findAll(items: ["c", "a", "b", "c", "a"], itemToFind: "c")        // result: [0, 3]
print(Indexes2!)



func offsetValue(input: String.CharacterView, position: String.CharacterView.Index) -> Int {
  let offset = input.distance(from: input.startIndex, to: position)
  return offset
}

var i = 0
let stringChars = "Hello, playground!".characters
let stringIndexes = findAll(items: stringChars, itemToFind: Character("l"))       // result: [2, 3, 8]
print("[", terminator: "")
for  stringIndex in stringIndexes! {
  let stringIndexInt = offsetValue(input:stringChars, position: stringIndex)
  print("\(stringIndexInt)", terminator: "")
    i += 1
  if i < (stringIndexes?.count)! {
    print(", ", terminator: "")
  }
}
print("]")
```